# Converting epoch time from Micro to milli second in Java

Tags: java

I have java program which is receiving time in Epoch in micro second as shown below

```
String time  = "1487809901812";
```

I need to convert this time from micro second to milli second before sending to some other system.

I want final value to be like

```
String final  = "1487809901.812";  //Note DOT here
```

I can easily do it by some string operation by placing dot before last three digits. But wondering is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it into `double`, divide it by 1000 and use `String.format` to format it, e,g.:

```
String time  = "1487809901812";
String milli = String.format("%.3f", Double.parseDouble(time)/1000.0);
System.out.println(milli);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String time  = "1487809901812";
time = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(time)/1000).setScale(3, 4).toString();
System.out.println(time);
//must be "1487809901.812";
```